# amazon-sagemaker-lab:: libXrender.so.1 package

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, rdkit

I am trying to use the amazon sagemaker lab environment and the package libXrender is not installed.

sudo privileges are removed and it's not possible to install it with:

`apt-get install libxrender1`

Is there an easy fix or do I have to contact their support to install the package in their docker container?

Thanks in advance!

Error results from this piece of code:

```
from rdkit.Chem.Draw import rdMolDraw2D
from rdkit.Chem.Draw.rdMolDraw2D import *

ImportError: libXrender.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

No problem in installing rdkit. The problem crops up when trying to call one of its visualisation functions **rdkit.Chem.Draw.rdMolDraw2D** - MolDraw2D requires the help of a rendering library to display the molecules in 2D.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sudo privileges are not available in Studio Lab. Your best bet is to find a different library that you can install without sudo privileges.

You can also try - `conda install -c conda-forge rdki`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `rdkit`, we can install it by `conda install -c conda-forge rdkit` in Studio Lab.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling upon this Q because they have a `libXrender.so.1` but with root or fakeroot powers, `yum install libxrender` still causes an error —in Fedora it's libXrender, libXrender1 in Debian, so the apt-get will likely be unhelpful.

In a bulletin board answer [Greg Landrum posits it's an X11 issue](https://sourceforge.net/p/rdkit/mailman/rdkit-discuss/thread/CAD4fdRTfVC64MgEiqNvx-RnXjsyHUpebR=VYw_9XiGPd5VGe2g@mail.gmail.com/), and suggests:

```
conda install -c rdkit nox
conda install -c rdkit cairo
```

In my case, a Rocky9 Singularity build (`library/default/rockylinux:9`) installing the following did the job of fixing X11 —which I assume might cause drama elsewhere:

```
dnf config-manager --enable crb
# CRB is powertools
    yum install xterm xorg-x11-server-Xorg xorg-x11-server-utils xorg-x11-xauth -y
#the xorg-x11-apps is deprecated
```